# Does organic food have more antioxidants than nonorganic food?

Tags: nutrition, organic-food

I know that there are a lot of studies out there that claim that organic food is not significantly different than nonorganic food in nutritional content, but this [new study](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBJN%2FS0007114514001366a.pdf&code=12fba04b4d47d1e24579326df0a7aa58) seems to challenge this claim.

Is this study legitimate? It is a meta-analysis, and uses many peer reviewed papers to come to it's conclusions, but are the methods correct? It just seems surprising to me, since the consensus seemed to be that organic food and nonorganic food are not significantly different, and this is not new research, but a meta-analysis, so how did it come to a different conclusion than the consensus?

Comment: There is no consensus among the scientific community that organic and non-organic food are not significantly different. They are obviously different. The question is whether organic food is somehow 'healthier' than non-organic food. The public opinion seems to be that this is an obviously true statement. The scientific evidence on the other hand demonstrates that this is not the case in general.

Comment: @PandaBear "They are obviously different" - obvious to who? Please back up that statement with a reference. The "organic" label has nothing to do with the output product. It only depends on the process. "The question is whether organic food is somehow 'healthier' than non-organic food." - No, the question is whether organic food has more antioxidants.

Comment: @Articuno I was being vague and you called me out.Organic food is different from non-organic food in the way it is produced, it is a matter of fact. That's why they are different. The organic label or any label for that matter has everything to do with the output product, I don't understand what you mean. You are right that's not the question OP asked, but it was what I thought he intended by the sentence 'consensus....different'. I took it literally and felt the need to inform the OP that it should be paraphrased differently, something along the lines of what I wrote.

Comment: What I meant was that the organic label does not place any standards on characteristics of the output product, only on the methods of production.